# How many direct successors of a basic block in LLVM IR can there be at most?

Tags: llvm

My switch code block converted to LLVM IR was transformed into an if branch, is it possible that the basic block of LLVM IR has up to two direct successors?

Number of direct successors to the basic block in LLVM IR.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can have more. It depends on the kind of [terminator](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#a7653277511df1034148a37520a585bb5) used in the block. There are five kinds of terminators IIRC:

- `ret` has no successors
- `br` has one or two
- `invoke` has two
- `switch` has two or more
- `unreachable` has none

`switch` commonly has tens of direct successors.